# Problem adding pdfpages to current class and/or tex file

Tags: packages, pdf, pdfpages

The following .tex script complies perfectly on my computer:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{Elanderphdmath.pdf}
\end{document}
```

However, no matter if I put

```
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
```

in the class file, or if I put

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

in the main tex file that uses the class file, I get the same errors, primarily

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
```

which occurs at some random location where there is normally no problem.
Again, these errors occur simply by adding the \usepackage or \RequirePackage command.  Has anyone heard of any conflicts with this package and other packages?  I don't have the first clue why it's not working.  Thanks in advance!

Update 20110419 0955: I am using MikTex 2.9 on Windows 7.  I just added all packages necessary (I hope) for pdfpages to run properly.  I'm assuming this is true since the sample code ran perfectly (see above).  I have two files, the class file and the main file.  Here is the header for the class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]     % Minimal LaTeX version required
\ProvidesClass{unlvmathesis}[2010/3/13 UNLV Math Thesis class v1.0]
\LoadClassWithOptions{report}

% REQUIRED PACKAGES ----------------------------------------------------------
% Note that they are also included as comments where they are used.

\RequirePackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, amssymb}
\RequirePackage{epsfig}
\RequirePackage{float}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}
%\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
```

Here is the header for the main TEX document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{unlvmathesis}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float,caption,array,multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx,graphics,epsfig,pictexwd}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
```

Let me know if there is any more info that I can provide which would be useful.

Update: 4:21pm.  After some reading, I see that the calc package affects the setcounter function.  The errors are occurring only at the \section locations.  In the class file, this is the only line that I see that is related to section numbering:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}    % SUBSECTIONS ARE NOT NUMBERED
```

Maybe something is undefined that the calc package is choking on?  Does everything have to be initialized?

Update 4:50pm:
At the first section in the first chapter, I get all of the following error messages:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \afterassignment 
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@hangfrom #1->\setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {{#1}}
                                              \hangindent \wd \@tempboxa \no...
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\H@old@sect ...c }\interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par }
                                                  \endgroup \csname #1mark\e...
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next 
                                                  {\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \calc@next 

l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \vskip 
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.4 \section{History of Metamaterials}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 6.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 6.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2009/06/22 v3.00 AMS symbols B
)
```

I get all of these same error messages for every \section of every chapter.  So, it's got something to do with incorporating the Calc package and sections.

Comment: Can you give some details about the distribution (miktex,texlive,mactex,...) you use and when you did your last system update? It seems like an error in the calc package

Comment: the calc package was last updated yonks ago; i assume something (possibly pdfpages) is doing something naughty with calc -- example code would be nice (it could be difficult to come up with code to do it "deliberately")

Comment: Ok, I have edited my question to give you the headers of both the class and the main tex documents.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, I just installed MikTex 2.9 a few months ago when I bought this new PC.  I am doing the updating right now, and I will keep my fingers crossed that it'll help, but I'm skeptical.

Comment: I just did the package updates, but nothing has changed.

Comment: I tried the above (incomplete) code and it works fine for me (latest TeXLive 2010). Please try to minimize your class to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that still shows the issue and post it here. Otherwise we can't do much.

Comment: One of your packages seem to be incompatible with the `calc` package (which is loaded by another package). Try to disable each package one-by-one to find the one which creates the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had almost the same problem, and the workaround suggested at http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/tMRBZ9hKeamEnltObBFi solves it!  It has to do with an interaction of calc and apacite and counters.

Hope it helps!

---Edited as suggested to include the workaround---
Here's an extract of the workaround suggested in the link above.  (A further reply to that post suggests that the latest version of apacite should take this into account and solve this.  I haven't tested it though.)

=============== Extract begin ==========================

I've tested your example and found that the incompatibility
is triggered by the use of the  calc.sty  package
...

More specifically,  calc.sty  changes the way  \setcounter  works.
The programming in  apacite.sty  does not take this into account.
The problem occurs when using \citet and other \cite command variants
defined by  natbib.sty , since these require significant extra parsing
beyond what LaTeX would do without  natbib .

Here's a simple fix that seems to work:

```
\usepackage[tocbib]{apacite}
%%  ----  RRM  2008/10/03
%% for compatibility with calc.sty
%% we need an extra \protect as below before  \setcounter
%%
\renewcommand{\BCnt}[1]{\protect\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\protect
\theBibCnt}
\renewcommand{\BCntIP}[1]{\protect\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\mbox{- 
\protect\theBibCnt}}
\renewcommand{\BCntND}[1]{\protect\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\mbox{- 
\protect\theBibCnt}}
...
```

This avoids \setcounter being expanded too early, at a place
where it isn't actually being used.
All still works correctly at the place where it *is* required.

An alternative solution, and perhaps a better one, would be
to have made the commands  \BCnt  \BCntIP  \BCntND  robust
in the first place; e.g.  apacite.sty   should use

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\BCnt}[1]{\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\theBibCnt}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\BCntIP}[1]{\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\mbox{- \theBibCnt}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\BCntND}[1]{\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\mbox{- \theBibCnt}}
```

You can patch this solution cleanly into existing documents,
as follows:

```
...
\DeclareRobustCommand{\robustBCnt}[1]{\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\theBibCnt}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\robustBCntIP}[1]{\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\mbox{- 
\theBibCnt}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\robustBCntND}[1]{\setcounter{BibCnt}{#1}\mbox{- 
\theBibCnt}}
\let\BCnt\robustBCnt
\let\BCntIP\robustBCntIP
\let\BCntND\robustBCntND
 ...
```

=============== Extract end ==========================

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please add at least the main part of the workaround to your answer. Answers here should be mostly self-contained and external links can break.

Comment: On second look: The linked post suggests to patch the `apacite` package to support the `calc` package. That changes should already be added to `apacite`. Anyway that package seems not be used by the OP, but another package might have similar incompatibilities! So the OP should have a look which package(s) that is.